# Does "python main.py" and "python /home/work/main.py" run differently

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7

I run a python script with "python main.py" in the shell under the main.py directory, it reports an errors and stops.But when I run the same script with full path like "python /home/work/main.py" under the same circumstance, It is blocked until I interrupt it with "Ctrl+C", a error is reported when it is interrupted.But it seems go the same and normally if no errors exist.

I don't know why, can somebody tell me ?

the errors:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/work/video/fe/tvservice/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    from conf.settings import DATABASE_TV, WEB_SERVER_CONFIG, DATABASE_TV_MASTER,DATABASE_TV_LOG_MASTER, ZOOKEEPER_CONFIG
  File "/home/work/video/fe/tvservice/conf/settings.py", line 1
    hello world
              ^
```

settings.py
hello world

Comment: It's better to paste the error informations here.

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing. Could you tell us what errors you were getting when you ran each piece of code? Also, when you execute the first one: `python main.py`, make sure you are in the correct directory by using `cd /home/work` before you execute the main.py file.

Comment: @venus.w: It looks like a `SyntaxError`, but the traceback should include information about type of the error.

Comment: In short, Tadeck's answer is correct. There should be no difference if they are in fact the same file aside from `sys.argv[0]` being different. Executing it through a different path has no effect on how the script runs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing it from *exactly* the same directory, and you are executing *exactly* the same file, most should be the same. The difference that you could possibly think about is value of:

```py
sys.argv[0]  # will be either '/home/work/main.py' or 'main.py'
```

Just make sure that:

- you are executing the same file,
- you are using the same virtual environment (or not using it in both cases),
- you are executing the command from the same directory,

Results for the following should be exactly the same:

```py
# Imports, so the commands will not fail
import os
import sys

# These should be the same in both cases - print them/log/whatever and compare
os.getcwd()
sys.path
```